# How to properly connect mongo replica set container with nodejs app container?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I am trying to connect my node.js application with MongoDB container. I tried googling and I think that I am doing everything correctly. The problem is that from localhost when I start my app with `npm run start` and use mongo connection string `mongodb://localhost:27017/databaseDev?authSource=admin` everything works perfectly. The problem is that the same containerized app from docker compose cannot connect mongo with `mongodb://mongo:27017/databaseDev?authSource=admin`. The docker compose that I am using is

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:4.4.15
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb/data:/data/db
      - ./mongodb/init-mongo.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.sh
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: 'databaseDev'
    command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all"]

  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/app
      - /var/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3010:3010
    environment:
      PORT: 3010
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
      DB_HOST: 'mongo'
      DB_PORT: 27017
      DB_NAME: 'databaseDev'
depends_on:
      - mongo
    command: ['node', 'dist/main']
```

init-mongo.sh file:

```bash
mongo -- "$MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE" <<EOF
    rs.initiate();
    rs.status();
EOF
```

and Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.15.1 as build
WORKDIR /var/app
COPY . .
RUN npm ci
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

Do you know what can be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to a replica set without specifying it in your connection URI.

First, you should add `&replicaSet=rs0` to your connection URI.

I am not a pro in Docker, but as far as I understood, you are exposing port 3010 in your docker container, but trying to connect to 27017.

Comment: `PORT` is the port that the application is listening on. `DB_PORT` describes the port of the mongo

Comment: It still does not work after applying your suggestions